# Websockets only PONG responses are received

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, socketrocket, starscream

I have implemented [SocketRocket](https://github.com/facebookarchive/SocketRocket) for websocket communication in my app but as this library is too old and archived for now, we decided to implement [StarScream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) which seems to be trustable.

However, after my migration from **SocketRocket => StarScream**, I found that only `PONG` responses are received for my websockets and other requests are not being responded.

Would anyone help me here find the issue or correct me?

Here is my [SocketRocket implementation](https://gist.github.com/mobihunterz/85e50b71d0d5b09439a3fea31da95b07#file-state-socketrocket-swift) where my websockets are working fine even in current live production app.

Here is my [StarScream implementation](https://gist.github.com/mobihunterz/85e50b71d0d5b09439a3fea31da95b07#file-state-starscream-swift) which is not working even with Production configuration, I use same production configs for both apps but SocketRocket works while StarScream fails.

If you check code, you will see lot of similarity with both implementation, even though I am not receiving proper response for StarScream implementation. I try to send ping requests every 2 seconds for which I get `PONG` response but I also do send `auth` request once socket is connected for which I never get any response while in SocketRocket I do get response for auth request.

- connectSocket() is the function where sockets are being created. Please ignore connectQuickStashSocket() for now as I have commented it temporarily.
- sendPing() is also omitted for now as I have to check response for auth, so, commented sendPing() call for every 2 seconds.
- send() is the main function where writing data on socket takes place
  and I also get completion callback once data is written, still I
  don't get any response.

**NOTE:** Commenting/uncommenting `sendPing()`, `connectQuickStashSocket()` will not change the response and the code behaves same.

Here I am attaching logs for SocketRocket where you will see all request/response working fine:

```
>>>> Connected to Socket
Optional("d2ee02da-e4de-4593-90e6-36598c00982d")
>>>> 
{
  "kind" : "auth",
  "uuid" : "",
  "auth" : {
    "version" : "1.4.0",
    "privateKey" : "d2ee02da-e4de-4593-90e6-36598c00982d",
    "device" : {
      "type" : "ios",
      "properties" : [

      ],
      "id" : "A5F24445-C688-43B0-98C1-96C636EFA08F"
    }
  }
}
>>>> Finished receiving socket data in 0.0020380020141601562 seconds
>>>> Deserialized pong data of length 25 in 0.0008620023727416992 seconds
>>>> Finished receiving socket data in 0.33321893215179443 seconds
>>>> Deserialized auth data of length 95 in 7.49826431274414e-05 seconds
>>>> 
{
  "sync" : {
    "collections" : {
      "24191c17-463c-4de9-b718-cad41976460c:stash" : {
        "cache" : {
          "e4d4804e-07a4-49f5-91f4-1b65935d4d8e" : 1,
          "8834da09-a26d-4a0f-806a-f3c54fff175e" : 1,
          "98a01deb-cfc7-4939-a6ce-d2dc64afe3a8" : 1,
          "80986d67-e0a4-4f4d-85c0-e263989f0044" : 1,
          "dd54420d-553b-4f43-808e-6cbdfcd0fe76" : 1,
          "1da73786-da7c-4b3f-b99f-58b907d15cc2" : 2,
          "c32c0a9a-c754-412e-af42-b8859a56ca72" : 1
        }
      },
      "24191c17-463c-4de9-b718-cad41976460c:inbox" : {
        "cache" : {

        }
      }
    }
  },
  "kind" : "sync"
}
>>>> Finished receiving socket data in 0.421644926071167 seconds
>>>> Deserialized sync data of length 2473 in 0.000841975212097168 seconds
Processed json and written to realm in 0.0073059797286987305 seconds
Initial state processed
```

Here is logs for StarScream where only `PONG` is received and response for `auth` request is not received, it only shows data written as request:

```
>>>> websocket is connected: ["Upgrade": "websocket", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true", "Date": "Tue, 12 May 2020 16:55:18 GMT", "Expect-CT": "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"", "cf-request-id": "02ab68f8400000dcd233395200000001", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "wss://mercury.speare.io", "CF-Cache-Status": "DYNAMIC", "CF-RAY": "5925aaa06d91dcd2-SIN", "Sec-WebSocket-Accept": "szN0nnvUplvghVle+n4FXOFp2cw=", "Server": "cloudflare", "Connection": "upgrade"]
Connected to Socket
Optional("d2ee02da-e4de-4593-90e6-36598c00982d")
{
  "kind" : "auth",
  "auth" : {
    "privateKey" : "d2ee02da-e4de-4593-90e6-36598c00982d",
    "version" : "1.4.0",
    "device" : {
      "id" : "A5F24445-C688-43B0-98C1-96C636EFA08F",
      "type" : "ios",
      "properties" : [

      ]
    }
  },
  "uuid" : ""
}
>>>> Received data: 47
Finished receiving socket data in 0.0007439851760864258 seconds
Deserialized data pong of length 25 in 0.0006880760192871094 seconds
2020-05-12 22:25:18.520913+0530 Stash[3952:884630] Socket done writing data => auth
```

**Please suggest me here what I can do and how to track what is the actual problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing different error which I got to know once I setup dev environment on my local machine and connected websockets over there.

I checked logs from server and got that it was giving me `zlib - gzip : invalid header`.

So, the issue was that server not sending any response as it was not getting the request in proper format.

I updated gzip library via POD and now my sockets are working perfect.

Whew..!